# Thermistor Steinhart-Hart coefficient ABC

Tags: thermistor

I am wondering how to find the Steinhart-Hart coefficients for the thermistor model
RL0503-5820-97-MS, and was given [this data sheet](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1344383.pdf?_ga=1.247384772.1124782096.1481069493). Where do I find these?

Answer (score 2):

### You only have half the equation

That datasheet isn't intended to be read by itself (it's terribly unfortunate that the links in it are broken, too).  You'll want [this document](http://www.amphenol-sensors.com/en/component/edocman/292-thermometrics-temperature-resistance-curves/download?Itemid=7966) to go with it, as it's where the temperature curves for the various materials got put (don't ask me why).  The Steinhart-Hart coefficients are in the bottom two tables on the left side of the page for the D9.7A material your thermistor uses (page 69 in the linked PDF).